# @Scheduled al arrancar Spring con servidor

Tags: java, spring, cron

Como puedo ejecutar una tarea programada en Spring al arrancar una aplicación web con un servidor Tomcat, intento que al ejecutar Spring con un servidor me ejecute esta tarea programada sencilla:

```
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
public class ScheduledTasks {
    
     @Bean
     public TaskScheduler scheduler() {
         return new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();
     }
     
    @Scheduled(cron = "*/5 * * * * *", zone = "America/Bogota")
    public void deactivateInscriptions() {
        
        System.out.println("Test");
    }
}
```

Pero veo que no hace nada ni se ejecuta el mensaje en la consola del servidor, agradecería su ayuda.

Comment: No necesitas Tomcat para este, simplemente lo ejecuta con `java -jar`

Comment: La verdad si lo necesito por que ando trabajando en una aplicación web (.war) ya lo probé como dices y funciona pero necesito que funcione al arrancarlo con un servidor web que en este caso ando utilizando tomcat.

Comment: A mi me funciona sin problemas, he usado spring boot  2.3.2 y un apache tomcat 8.5 he desplegado la app como un war, deberiamos proveernos mas informacion como si ustas usando spring boot o spring clasico y que version ademas del sistema operativo.

Comment: Utilizo Spring clásico con configuraciones XML (Por requerimiento), y tambien e intentado con Spring Boot y hay si me funciona pero con el Spring Clasico no me funciona al ejecutarlo con un servidor y ando utilizando Windows 10.

Comment: Lo que sucede es que por tener la librería de spring en un proyecto war no quiere decir que se incie automáticamente, primero deberíamos saber que tecnología esta utilizando si es JSP, JSF, Spring MVC, etc. porque cada tipo de proyecto tiene su forma de configurar el inicio. Luego hay formas de hacerlo utilizando Java o con Quartz para casos mas complejos, porque agregar Spring solo por el Scheduler lo veo algo extremista por todo el peso, funciones y configuración solo por ejecutar tareas.

Comment: @RobertoEMoran gracias por responder, efectivamente ando utilizando Spring MVC con JSP en las vistas y la verdad te agradecería como podría realizar eso que me indicas con las tecnologías que ando utilizando.